# How to push a view controller over the UISplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, ipad

How do I push a view control over a UISPlitViewController?  Or How do I get the parent UIViewController of the UISplitViewController?

What I want to do is when a user clicks on a button a UiViewController will take up the enter ipad view.

I currently have this hierarchy:

```
Window
   UISplitViewController
```

I want to push a new UIController to take up or replace the UISplitViewController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show your view controller from a view controller using `presentModalViewController:animated:` and it will by default cover up the entire screen and animate from bottom to top if you pass YES for animated.

```
MyModalViewController *mvc = [[MyModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:mvc animated:YES];
[mvc release];
```

Comment: By the way, to close the modal vc, you use dismissModalViewControllerAnimated.  You could call this from the modal vc itself but I prefer to use a NSNotification or delegate to inform the parent vc that the modal is done and have the parent call the dismiss so the present/dismiss match up and the parent vc knows exactly when the modal closes and gives an easy way to pass data back if needed.

Comment: the only caveat here is that when presenting it modally you cannot have the background transparent. so if you are planning on showing a progress or load bar - no go.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] getKeyWindow].rootViewController = newViewController;`

I'm actually not sure if getKeyWindow is the exact method name, it might be something slightly different.

Comment: But I want to make sure the original UISplitViewCOntroller is still there when the user closes out of the newViewController.

Comment: ANd I also want to animate it from Bottom to Top